# Select and retrieve contacts from excel in flutter?

Tags: excel, flutter, xlsx, xls

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:excel/excel.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainPageTest2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Excel File Picker'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: pickExcelFileAndExtractData,
          child: Text('Select Excel File'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<void> pickExcelFileAndExtractData() async {
  FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
    type: FileType.custom,
    allowedExtensions: ['xls', 'xlsx'],
  );

  if (result != null) {
    File file = File(result.files.single.path!);
    var bytes = file.readAsBytesSync();
    var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);

    if (excel.tables.isNotEmpty) {
      var table = excel.tables[excel.tables.keys.first];

      // Assuming contacts are in column A and usernames are in column B
      for (var row in table!.rows) {
        var contact = row[0]?.value;
        var username = row[1]?.value;

        // Do something with the contact and username data
        print('Contact: $contact, Username: $username');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

> Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: Excel format unsupported.

[Demo excel](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MKE55ThIC4uu1fE2aS6vIYGV7khkdV6I?usp=sharing)

I'm getting this error after selecting Excel to retrieve contacts and username from. I tried with demo Excel in which there will be column of username and contacts. From that I want to extract username and contacts but after selecting Excel file error is showing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately xls files are not supported in excel library.